# Ubuntu boot stuck on tty1 screen

Tags: boot, drivers, login, dependencies, gui

I installed Ubuntu 22.04.02 and it was working just fine since last month , but then suddenly it got stuck at the login screen , I wasn't able to enter my password. I used the power key to force shutdown it but since then whenever I boot into my system,Ubuntu tty1 screen opens up and I can't switch to GUI . Tried all methods I found online , nothing worked yet.No shortcuts , not reinstalling
This what opens up

Tried using sudo apt-get install --reinstall Ubuntu desktop
But I get this

Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree... Done Reading state information... Done

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have

requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created

or been moved out of Incoming.

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies: libeg1-mesao: Depends: libgomi (= 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.122.04.1) but 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.122.04. E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Comment: Your message appears to be a 3rd party package, as I don't find it (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libgomi&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) so explore what 3rd party package(s) you've added to your system that have created the *conflict* or *dep* issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar this morning, I am still not sure what happened but it started with only one of my monitors showing, then ubuntu GUI logged in but looked basic then after a reboot I didnt even get the login and my tty1 (gnome) ended up with just a blinking cursor.

It looks like it was the nvidia drivers, I did a number of things but I think just the following fixed it: -

- Ctrl-Alt-F2 and log into a console then
- sudo apt update
- sudo apt upgrade
- sudo apt full-upgrade

See if your nvidia drivers are part of the build.